# How can I view output of tshark -V via Wireshark or similar?

Tags: sip, wireshark, rtp, hexdump, tshark

Recently updated my Wireshark on a server, and lost the ability to use -R and -w from the CLI. Since I'm tracing SIP and RTP calls, I need to use -R and not -f.

I found out using -V is very useful (shows the packet tree on screen) and then I can redirect the output to a file. Unfortunately I'm not able to open that file through Wireshark to view properly (contains too muh text to easily scroll through).

I tried using -x t add the hex dump (removed -V), but still that is not openable through Wireshark when copying the text file to my PC.

Any ideas how I can trace using -R (with or without -V), copy the file to my PC and still be able to read it through Wireshark? I don't have issues to convert the file to a readable format.. Just need anything to view the files and share them :)

Thanks all,

//M

Comment: Any thoughts or ideas anyone?:)